# Shut down a UDP Server receiving requests

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winsock

I made a UDP server class and my program creates a process (running in the background). It is a command line utility, and so running 'udpserver.exe start' would bind the socket and begin a blocking `recvfrom()` call inside a `for(;;)` loop.

What is the best way to safely and 'gracefully' stop the server?

I was thinking about 'udpserver.exe stop' would send a udp msg such as 'stop' and the ongoing process from 'udpserver.exe start' would recognize this msg, break from the loop, and clean up (closesocket/wsacleanup).

Also, is just killing the process not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running the UDP server as an external process instead of as a worker thread inside of your main program? That would make it a lot easier to manage the server.  Simple close the socket, which will abort a blocked `recvfrom()`, thus allowing the thread to terminate itself.

But if you must run the UDP server in an external process, personally I would just kill that process, quick and simple. But if you really want to be *graceful* about it, you could make the server program handle <kbd>CTRL-BREAK</kbd> via [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016.aspx) so it knows when it needs to close its socket, stopping `recvfrom()`.  Then you can have the main program spawn the server program via [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) with the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag to get a group ID that can then be used to send <kbd>CTRL-BREAK</kbd> to the server process via [`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155.aspx) when needed.

Comment: I'm integrating my work into an existing program that starts up an external process (pretty sure it's `CreateProcess()`. I actually do create a worker thread that does the `recvfrom()` if 'udpserver.exe start' is run. If the process is already running, how would `closesocket()` recognize/know which/where the socket is to close?

Comment: If you put the socket into its own process, then THAT process has to be the one to close the socket that it creates for itself. Hence my suggestion to send CTRL-C to the process so it knows when to close its socket.

Comment: I ended up making a CloseServer() function where it sends a message to the server, the server recognizes the messages and cleans up. Do you think this is also fine?

Comment: By doing that, you are opening the server to be shut down by your UDP clients. Is that what you really want? Your best option is to not use a separate process at all. Otherwise, at least consider an alternative signal for shutdown, such as a named event object via `CreateEvent()`. Your server could wait on the event and shutdown when the main program signals the event with `SetEvent()`.